# Gradle plugin for creating ejb client

Tags: gradle, ejb, client

Are there any plugins in gradle for creating ejb client stubs? Maven have the  maven-ejb-plugin (http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-ejb-plugin/examples/generating-ejb-client.html). Are there any equivalents for gradle, or can I use the maven plugin from gradle?

Comment: Please don't double-post a question on the Gradle forum and on Stackoverflow.

Comment: Why not? Does all the people on Stack Overflow read the Gradle forum and vice versa?

Comment: @BenjaminMuschko sounds like a meta thing, but, IMHO, you're kinda right -- but **link** one to the other.  That would make it ok.  Speaking of which, if someone would link to the forum answer..